# Is it natural to say "She is complicated. She is long on temper but short on patience"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Suppose there is a woman who is not simple and often wants many different things in life, which makes her life more complicated because she has to manage so many things she possesses.

Is it correct to say "**She is complicated. She is long on temper but short on patience**"?

**Note**: I don't see any example in dictionaries say "**a person is complicated**"

Comment: It's an "unusual" wordplay, to say the least, since there is no idiomatic usage ***long on temper*** in English. Without this *exact* context to guide interpretation, I'd be as likely to suppose it meant *is slow to **cease** being angry* rather than *takes a long time to **become** angry*. The intended meaning is only clear because pf the context, which *unavoidably* proclaims "wordplay" at least as much as the delivery of information.

Comment: (Also, I don't find the text "natural" because it doesn't make sense. It seems to be saying she's simultaneously slow ***and*** quick to lose her temper / patience.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Patience is “willingness to wait”, and temper is emotional state. After staring at this for a few minutes, I'd interpret this to mean that somebody did not like waiting for things, but didn't get angry about it. I don't think that's what it's meant to mean, though; naturalness aside, neither of our interpretations match the first paragraph of this question.

Comment: *I don't see any example in dictionaries say "a person is complicated"* - one example usage which comes to mind is the [theme from Shaft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q429AOpL_ds).

Comment: FWIW, I interpreted that exactly the same way @wizzwizz4 described. If short-tempered is a thing, long-tempered must be the opposite.

Comment: What do you mean by "long in temper" as in **she has a temper that *lasts for a long time*** or that **it takes her a *long time* to lose her temper**?

Comment: Sounds 19th century. Temper is rarely a noun anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fine to say a person is complicated.
For your second sentence it might make as much sense to say

> She's long on temper *and* short on patience.

since you'd expect someone with a temper to be impatient.

Comment: I guess this shows how ambiguous ‘long on temper’ is: I interpreted it as meaning that it takes a long _time_ for her to lose her temper — which would be in opposition to the rest and justify the ‘but’. (Your interpretation — that she has a nasty temper — may make more sense when you think about it, though.)

Comment: Financial terminology: "long" means you own some, "short" means you don't (or that you have sold some).

Comment: Short-tempered means a person easily becomes angry, so I would assume "long on temper" would mean they don't get upset easily. But yes, phrasing it that way makes it harder to tease out a meaning. "Long-tempered" isn't a phrase but at least it would be clearly understandable by analogy.

Answer (score 8):

I've never heard of a long-tempered person. You could say quick-tempered, high-tempered, or simply 'she's got a temper' (insinuating the same thing) but 'long on temper' doesn't sound right to me.

As for a complicated person; that's a correct way to describe someone. The reason it's not in the dictionary is because 'complicated' has a generic meaning, and can apply to many things.

Comment: The question doesn't call the person long-tempered.  It simply uses the opposing *long* and *short* references for effect.

Comment: @Chenmunka knowing the user, I'd say they have used "long temper" because they believe it is idiomatic. To be described as being complicated suggests that the person has ***conflicting* personality traits**.

Comment: @Chenmunka Tom did ask 'Is it correct to say [..]'

Answer (score 2):

Definition 8 at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/long) provides the meaning of the idiom "long on":

> *informal* Well supplied with.

So "long on temper" means she has a strong temper. "Short on" is the opposite, so "short on patience" means she doesn't have much matience.

The relevant [definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/complicated) of "complicated" is:

> Involving many different and confusing aspects.

All people have many different aspects, so when we describe a person as complicated we're emphasizing that their particular combinations of personality traits are confusing. So this isn't really a very good example of being complicated, since this is hardly an unexpected combination.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a nice sentence. It’s not what you would usually hear, but it’s nice. English language isn’t fixed. This is just the right distance from standard English to be interesting.

Now what exactly “long on temper” means is tricky to say. “Short on temper” is someone who gets annoyed very easily and quickly. So “long on temper” might be someone who takes a very long time to get upset. But I read it as someone who gets angry easily and then stays angry for a long time. That’s mostly because of the contrast with “short of patience” which is someone losing their patience quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Use of 'long' and 'short' here make me think of financial trading, where to be 'long' on a commodity means to have a financial situation where you will profit if the price goes up (e.g. by owning some of it), or maybe just to believe that it's valuable and to be 'short' means to have the opposite situation, where you will profit if the price goes down, or you think it's not valuable enough to justify the price.

So someone long on temper and short on patience would like temper and dislike patience.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be less ambiguous if you say:
"She is **big** on temper but short on patience."

**long** does not clarify whether she takes long to be angry or whether she stays angry for a long time. Most people might understand the former meaning than the latter.

"Big on temper" makes more sense as being Big on something is the general usage that someone does it a lot or likes to do something a lot. Let me know what you think.

Comment: See the definition I quoted in my answer, it explains why "long on" is appropriate. "Temper" isn't something someone chooses to do or enjoy.